# Why won't python use os.startfile after using os.startfile once?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating an application which can jump through tkinter files.
The first one is a login screen which has the following definition:

```
if results:
    os.startfile("data\main.pyw")
    with open("data\logdat.txt","w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(username.get())
    root.destroy()
```

Next one is the main screen where all the menu options are.
Here is one specific button for a "calculator", so when the button is pressed it opens another tkinter file.

```
def balancecal():
    webbrowser.open(r"data\egyenleg.pyw")
    root.destroy()
```

But when initiating this, it closes the program.
I tried opening the main.py file itself, writing out the "\data" part from the balancecal definition, and with that it opened the file, so the file itself is found.. It just won't work after opening it through the default procedure (with going through the login screen too).

Can someone help me out please?
I'm still a beginner here.

Thanks!

Comment: `webbrowser.open` is an entirely different operation from `os.startfile`.  Your web browser has no clue what to do with a Python file.

Comment: It is just a try of many others. I tried using it with subprocess, os.startfile, and also this one. Everything is showing the same behaviour. Not opening the file. It skips through, it because it does the "root.destroy()" operation after that.

Comment: Why are you destroying the root? Launching new files from the main script seems like a bad idea, as you'll be creating a new instance of TK that can't communicate with your main script. Would importing your script into the main one (allowing you access to it's classes) work better?

Comment: Right.  The way you architect this kind of app is to have your windows in separate classes, then `import` those files and create the windows inline, NOT by starting separate disconnected applications.

Comment: Worth also just adding that if there is some particular reason you want to keep the applications disconnected, you should defer to `root.quit()` since this preserves access to the widgets in the original `mainloop()`